# How to SELECT a column twice from the same table in sql to show different value?

Tags: sql, qlikview

I want to show different value in Qlik sense dashboard, but I have to use same column from same table in SQL - how can I do this?

Here is my code:
"first"

```
LOAD WORKORDERID As ID,
    REQUESTERID as RqId,
    TITLE As Subject,
SQL SELECT WORKORDERID,
    REQUESTERID,
    TITLE,
FROM servicedesk.dbo.WorkOrder;
```

---

```
LOAD WORKORDERID As ID,
    CATEGORYID,
    SUBCATEGORYID As SID,
    OWNERID as TechID,
    ASSIGNEDTIME,
    REQUESTTYPEID;
SQL SELECT WORKORDERID,
    CATEGORYID,
    SUBCATEGORYID,
    OWNERID,
    ASSIGNEDTIME,
    REQUESTTYPEID
FROM servicedesk.dbo.WorkOrderStates;
```

now i want to show my queue name and want to use workorderID again :

```
LOAD QUEUEID As QID,
     QUEUENAME;
SQL SELECT QUEUEID,
    QUEUENAME
FROM servicedesk.dbo.QueueDefinition;

LOAD WORKORDERID;
SQL SELECT WORKORDERID
FROM servicedesk.dbo.WorkOrder;

LOAD WORKORDERID,
    QUEUEID ;
SQL SELECT WORKORDERID,
    QUEUEID
FROM servicedesk.dbo."WorkOrder_Queue";
```

Comment: Can you show a sample output with column names?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code as pictures - [edit] your question and paste the code as text (properly formatted) instead.

Comment: Please do not post images (links of) code - cannot cut 'n' paste them!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to display the value from a single column twice in the same query, you can use [SQL Aliases](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp).

```
SELECT
    column_name,
    column_name AS `column_name_2`
FROM table;
```

Comment: No i know aliases as well but i think i should create a new table , i edit my question so you can read it again, thanks

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to achieve here, what should your ultimate query look like?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ‘NoConcatenate’?

Ex:
LIB CONNECT TO 'QV_table';
LOAD aa,
          bb,
          cc;
SQL SELECT aa,
                      bb,
                      cc
FROM ADWorks.dba.'table1';

LIB CONNECT TO 'QV_table';
NoConcatenate
LOAD aa          AS AAT1,
          ee,
          ff;
SQL SELECT aa, 
                      ee,
                      ff
FROM ADWorks.dba.'table1';